# Installing ImageMagick on a Linux VPS

Tags: linux, php, vps, imagemagick

I need to install ImageMagick on a 1&1 Linux VPS.

So I open putty, I log in, I type `yum install ImageMagick`

Then it tells me it needs to download about 90MB of packages, update a few others, and maybe then it will finally install ImageMagick. Within that big list there are a big bunch of stuff, as far as I can understand they're uncommon to a VPS environment (audio libraries, X window system, even Gnome), check this out:

```
Installing:
 ImageMagick             i386       6.2.8.0-15.el5_8  updates           3.3 M
 ImageMagick             x86_64     6.2.8.0-15.el5_8  updates           3.3 M
Updating:
 bzip2-libs              x86_64     1.0.3-6.el5_5    base               35 k
 cups-libs               x86_64     1:1.3.7-30.el5   base              196 k
 dbus                    x86_64     1.1.2-16.el5_7   base              234 k
 freetype                x86_64     2.2.1-31.el5_8.1  updates           312 k
 glib2                   x86_64     2.12.3-4.el5_3.1  base              693 k
 gnutls                  x86_64     1.4.1-7.el5_8.2  updates           365 k
 libX11                  x86_64     1.0.3-11.el5_7.1  base              798 k
 libacl                  x86_64     2.2.39-8.el5     base               20 k
 libgcrypt               x86_64     1.4.4-5.el5_8.2  updates           233 k
 libpng                  x86_64     2:1.2.10-17.el5_8  updates           235 k
 libtiff                 x86_64     3.8.2-15.el5_8   updates           314 k
 libusb                  x86_64     0.1.12-6.el5     base               27 k
 libxml2                 x86_64     2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.2  updates           809 k
 popt                    x86_64     1.10.2.3-28.el5_8  updates            78 k
 rpm-libs                x86_64     4.4.2.3-28.el5_8  updates           925 k
Installing for dependencies:
 GConf2                  i386       2.14.0-9.el5     base              1.5 M
 GConf2                  x86_64     2.14.0-9.el5     base              1.5 M
 ORBit2                  i386       2.14.3-5.el5     base              252 k
 ORBit2                  x86_64     2.14.3-5.el5     base              263 k
 alsa-lib                x86_64     1.0.17-1.el5     base              414 k
 atk                     i386       1.12.2-1.fc6     base              222 k
 atk                     x86_64     1.12.2-1.fc6     base              224 k
 audiofile               x86_64     1:0.2.6-5        base              107 k
 avahi                   x86_64     0.6.16-10.el5_6  base              258 k
 avahi                   i386       0.6.16-10.el5_6  base              251 k
 avahi-glib              i386       0.6.16-10.el5_6  base               15 k
 avahi-glib              x86_64     0.6.16-10.el5_6  base               15 k
 bitstream-vera-fonts    noarch     1.10-7           base              343 k
 bzip2-libs              i386       1.0.3-6.el5_5    base               37 k
 cairo                   x86_64     1.2.4-5.el5      base              386 k
 cairo                   i386       1.2.4-5.el5      base              394 k
 chkfontpath             x86_64     1.10.1-1.1       base               15 k
 cryptsetup-luks         x86_64     1.0.3-8.el5      base              710 k
 cups-libs               i386       1:1.3.7-30.el5   base              200 k
 dbus-glib               i386       0.73-10.el5_5    base              161 k
 dbus-libs               i386       1.1.2-16.el5_7   base              124 k
 dbus-python             x86_64     0.70-9.el5_4     base              186 k
 dropbox                 x86_64     0.7.110-1.el4.rf  rpmforge           13 M
 esound                  x86_64     1:0.2.36-4       base              131 k
 fontconfig              i386       2.4.1-7.el5      base              174 k
 freetype                i386       2.2.1-31.el5_8.1  updates           312 k
 gamin                   i386       0.1.7-10.el5     base              120 k
 gamin                   x86_64     0.1.7-10.el5     base              129 k
 ghostscript             x86_64     8.70-14.el5      base              8.9 M
 ghostscript             i386       8.70-14.el5      base              9.0 M
 ghostscript-fonts       noarch     5.50-13.1.1      base              801 k
 glib2                   i386       2.12.3-4.el5_3.1  base              674 k
 gnome-keyring           x86_64     0.6.0-1.fc6      base              166 k
 gnome-mime-data         x86_64     2.4.2-3.1        base              691 k
 gnome-mount             x86_64     0.5-3.el5        base               70 k
 gnome-vfs2              i386       2.16.2-8.el5     base              1.2 M
 gnome-vfs2              x86_64     2.16.2-8.el5     base              1.3 M
 gnutls                  i386       1.4.1-7.el5_8.2  updates           351 k
 gtk2                    x86_64     2.10.4-21.el5_7.7  base              6.6 M
 gtk2                    i386       2.10.4-21.el5_7.7  base              6.5 M
 hal                     x86_64     0.5.8.1-62.el5   base              377 k
 hal                     i386       0.5.8.1-62.el5   base              395 k
 hicolor-icon-theme      noarch     0.9-2.1          base               25 k
 hwdata                  noarch     0.213.26-1.el5   base              423 k
 kbd                     x86_64     1.12-21.el5      base              1.3 M
 lcms                    i386       1.18-0.1.beta1.el5_3.2  base              176 k
 lcms                    x86_64     1.18-0.1.beta1.el5_3.2  base              177 k
 libFS                   x86_64     1.0.0-3.1        base               30 k
 libICE                  i386       1.0.1-2.1        base               54 k
 libIDL                  x86_64     0.8.7-1.fc6      base               87 k
 libIDL                  i386       0.8.7-1.fc6      base               85 k
 libSM                   i386       1.0.1-3.1        base               27 k
 libX11                  i386       1.0.3-11.el5_7.1  base              797 k
 libXau                  i386       1.0.1-3.1        base               18 k
 libXcomposite           x86_64     0.3-5.1          base               12 k
 libXcursor              i386       1.1.7-1.2        base               32 k
 libXcursor              x86_64     1.1.7-1.2        base               32 k
 libXdamage              x86_64     1.0.3-2.1        base               11 k
 libXdmcp                i386       1.0.1-2.1        base               19 k
 libXext                 i386       1.0.1-2.1        base               35 k
 libXfixes               x86_64     4.0.1-2.1        base               15 k
 libXfixes               i386       4.0.1-2.1        base               14 k
 libXfont                x86_64     1.2.2-1.0.4.el5_7  base              245 k
 libXft                  x86_64     2.1.10-1.1       base               44 k
 libXft                  i386       2.1.10-1.1       base               44 k
 libXi                   x86_64     1.0.1-4.el5_4    base               26 k
 libXi                   i386       1.0.1-4.el5_4    base               25 k
 libXinerama             x86_64     1.0.1-2.1        base              9.8 k
 libXinerama             i386       1.0.1-2.1        base              9.7 k
 libXrandr               x86_64     1.1.1-3.3        base               15 k
 libXrandr               i386       1.1.1-3.3        base               15 k
 libXrender              x86_64     0.9.1-3.1        base               28 k
 libXrender              i386       0.9.1-3.1        base               27 k
 libXres                 x86_64     1.0.1-3.1        base               14 k
 libXt                   i386       1.0.2-3.2.el5    base              173 k
 libacl                  i386       2.2.39-8.el5     base               19 k
 libart_lgpl             x86_64     2.3.17-4         base               75 k
 libattr                 i386       2.4.32-1.1       base               12 k
 libbonobo               i386       2.16.0-1.1.el5_5.1  base              502 k
 libbonobo               x86_64     2.16.0-1.1.el5_5.1  base              524 k
 libbonoboui             x86_64     2.16.0-1.fc6     base              394 k
 libcap                  i386       1.10-26          base               22 k
 libcroco                x86_64     0.6.1-2.1        base              129 k
 libcroco                i386       0.6.1-2.1        base              127 k
 libdaemon               i386       0.10-5.el5       base               24 k
 libdaemon               x86_64     0.10-5.el5       base               24 k
 libfontenc              x86_64     1.0.2-2.2.el5    base               19 k
 libgcrypt               i386       1.4.4-5.el5_8.2  updates           251 k
 libglade2               x86_64     2.6.0-2          base               96 k
 libgnome                x86_64     2.16.0-6.el5     base              860 k
 libgnomecanvas          x86_64     2.14.0-4.1       base              224 k
 libgnomeui              x86_64     2.16.0-5.el5     base              984 k
 libgpg-error            i386       1.4-2            base               60 k
 libgsf                  i386       1.14.1-6.1       base              116 k
 libgsf                  x86_64     1.14.1-6.1       base              113 k
 libjpeg                 i386       6b-37            base              139 k
 libnotify               x86_64     0.4.2-6.el5      base               38 k
 libpng                  i386       2:1.2.10-17.el5_8  updates           241 k
 librsvg2                i386       2.16.1-1.el5     base              178 k
 librsvg2                x86_64     2.16.1-1.el5     base              178 k
 libtiff                 i386       3.8.2-15.el5_8   updates           309 k
 libusb                  i386       0.1.12-6.el5     base               26 k
 libvolume_id            i386       095-14.27.el5_7.1  base               44 k
 libvolume_id            x86_64     095-14.27.el5_7.1  base               43 k
 libwmf                  x86_64     0.2.8.4-10.2     base              832 k
 libwmf                  i386       0.2.8.4-10.2     base              834 k
 libwnck                 x86_64     2.16.0-4.fc6     base              185 k
 libxml2                 i386       2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.2  updates           797 k
 notification-daemon     x86_64     0.3.5-9.el5      base               48 k
 pango                   i386       1.14.9-8.el5.centos.3  base              334 k
 pango                   x86_64     1.14.9-8.el5.centos.3  base              338 k
 pciutils                x86_64     3.1.7-5.el5      base              112 k
 pm-utils                x86_64     0.99.3-10.el5.centos  base              134 k
 popt                    i386       1.10.2.3-28.el5_8  updates            76 k
 shared-mime-info        x86_64     0.19-5.el5       base              149 k
 startup-notification    x86_64     0.8-4.1          base               32 k
 ttmkfdir                x86_64     3.0.9-23.el5     base               46 k
 urw-fonts               noarch     2.3-6.1.1        base              4.5 M
 xorg-x11-font-utils     x86_64     1:7.1-3          base               78 k
 xorg-x11-xfs            x86_64     1:1.0.2-5.el5_6.1  base               73 k
```

I fear that if I give it a green light to do whatever it wants, the VPS will never start again (after restart).

What should I do? I only want ImageMagick for PHP.

Comment: Build the parts you want from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageMagick was built with X11 and Gtk+ support, and so it pulls in a lot of dependencies. Some of the graphics libraries that ImageMagick uses also depend on parts of the windowing system. None of these will automatically start a graphical login on your system or break the boot process. So it's safe to install, but will use some disk space.

Comment: Worked with no obvious problems after restart.